¿Como transformar datos de columnas de Longitud y Latitud a datos X e Y para graficar en un campo de futbol? en Python
estoy intentando trabnsformar datos obtenidos de un gps, que me entrega datos de ubicacion de Latitud y Longitud, en datos XeY para poder graficar los recorridos en un campo de futbol. A travez de lo que pude investigar, tengo el siguiente codigo:
Primero, las coordenadas de referencia de la cancha:
#ESTADIO
reference_points = {
     'A' : ( -31.375566 ,-60.425855),  #BL 
     'B' : ( -31.375632 ,-60.425454), #BR
     'C' : ( -31.375333 ,-60.425806), #TL
     'D' : ( -31.375394 ,-60.425400) #TR

Luego la funcion para de conversion
#FUNCION DE FILTRO BUTTERWORTH
def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff,fs,order=5):
    nyq = 0.5*fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    c, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog = False)
    y = lfilter(c, a, data)
    return y

def convert_to_cartesian(lat, long):
    print(f'Input - Latitude: {lat}, Longitude: {long}')
    def map_from_to(x,a,b,c,d):
        y = (x - a) / (c - a) * (b - d) + d
        return y
    x = map_from_to(lat, reference_points['A'][1], reference_points['B'][1], 0, 105)
    y = map_from_to(long, reference_points['A'][0], reference_points['C'][0], 0, 70)
    return x,y
    
cutoff_frequency = 2.0
sampling_frequency = 10
order = 3
fs = 1000

aplico la funcion
df[['x', 'y']] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(convert_to_cartesian(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])), axis=1)
    

y este es el resultado que obtengo:

Es evidente que hay algo que no estoy haciendo bien y no logro corregirlo
Lo que busco es que las coordenadas XeY OBTENIDAS, se representen en un plano de 68 x 105 (medidas de la cancha), con la correspondiente transformacion de las Coordenadas obtenidas del GPS (Latitud y Longitud).

que deseas hacer exactamente? porque lo que explicas no es lo que se ve dado que intentas convertir a frecuencia...

Quiero transformar los valores de Latitud y Longitud en valores numericos para representarlos en un plano cartesiano, en una cancha de futbol

Hola Sports, la solución sencilla, es representar los puntos directamente desde sus correspondientes latitud y longitud (previamente adaptadas) esto es sumamente sencillo, pero te dibujará el estadio con la inclinación que tiene con respeto al ecuador, para alcanzar ese objetivo, debes llevar la menor latitud a "0", a todas las demás, le restas el valor de esta, lo mismo con las longitudes, luego multiplicas por el número que salga de dividir la resolucion de pantalla de su alterego mayor latitud/longitud (suponiendo que va a pantalla completa)

PD: los valores de latitud y longitud, debes "limpiarlos" dejando solo la sección que representa las diferencias, ejem. latA = 31.375566 latB = 31.375632, dejamos latA = 566 latB = 632, el otro camino, todavía lo estoy pensando, si encuentro la solución, la publico

La opcion mas sencilla seria hacer esto:
def latlon_to_xy(lat, lon, origin_lat, origin_lon):
    lat_to_m = 111320  # 1 grado de latitud en metros
    lon_to_m = 111320 * np.cos(np.radians(origin_lat))  # Ajustar para la longitud

    x = (lon - origin_lon) * lon_to_m
    y = (lat - origin_lat) * lat_to_m
    print(x,y)
    return x, y


# donde empezaremos a graficar
origin = reference_points['A']
points_xy = {}
for key, (lat, lon) in reference_points.items():
    x, y = latlon_to_xy(lat, lon, origin[0], origin[1])
    points_xy[key] = (x, y)


¿Qué resultados produce tu respuesta?
